# Relative comparisons of probabilities

Tags: probability

Let's say that I have three data sets. One shows that tobacco will decrease expected life span. Another shows that living near a pool will also decrease expected life span. The third shows that eating spinach increases expected life span.

How would one use these data sets in combination to show that (for life expectancy calculations) smoking X cigarettes is equivalent to living near a pool for Y days or consuming -Z grams of spinach?

In case there's not a direct and simple answer to this, what are mathematical topic that cover these types of problems?

Comment: A problem is that, for the sake of theory, your hypothesis has never been tested on humans, as in an observational cohort study, or randomized clinical trial (RCT) in which subjects are randomized to various treatments.  If you don't have results from a prospective cohort study of humans exposed to these factors, or an RCT, you would have to compare survivorship function $S(t)$ values across the groups based on empirical data.   Look into the logrank test for equality of survival.

Comment: Are these datasets measured on the same subjects?